# Help on selecting 2 tests - unsure if they are paired or non-paired statistical test

Tags: statistics, math-software, biology

I have data that measures the temperature of flowers and leaves on different plant species. These are the comparisons I am trying to make:

1. Comparing the flower and leaf of the *same* plant at the *same* time of day
2. Comparing the flower *or* leaf of a plant to the ***same*** flower *or* leaf at ***different*** times of day - on the same plant

My current interpretation is that 1 is an independent statistical test because while they are both on the same individual plant, they are separate "individuals" themselves. For 2 I believe it is a paired test as it is measuring the same flower or leaf at different times of day.

What is confusing me is that I have been taught that if it is the same "individual" then it should be paired, therefore 1 should be a paired test. However my interpretation is that "individual" means something different in the mathematical reality of the tests, where they are seen as different pools in this instance.

Am I correct in my thought? Or completely wrong?

Thank you

**Edit**: Maybe some clarification to my thought: The difference between my 2 tests is that one uses the same repeated leaf or flower (referring to case 2) at different times of day (therefore it is paired as it is a measurement of the same thing twice at different times). This contrasts with case 1 as this is comparing 2 different objects at the same time of day. The confusion for me comes in when case 2 is still on the same individual - they are related in a way, but I'm unsure if this is relevant to the test.

Comment: What is the difference between a test for a number of plants that just takes the average temperature of leaves and compares it to the average temperature of flowers, versus a test that compares the difference for each individual plant?

Comment: @PhilH I am unsure what you mean. But to clarify what I mean in this, the difference between my 2 tests is that one uses the same repeated leaf or flower (referring to case 2) at different times of day (therefore it is paired as it is a  measurement of the same thing twice at different times). This contrasts with case 1 as this is comparing 2 different objects at the same time of day. The confusion for me comes in when case 2 is still on the same individual - they are related in a way, but I'm unsure if this is relevant to the test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The experimental unit (presumably sampled at random from a relevant population) is the *plant.*

Looking at different parts of a plant gives two (paired) values per plant. Looking at different times a day gives two (paired) values per plant.

Both are paired tests.

While both kinds of tests look at averages of the data, the tests are fundamentally different.

***Example:***

Here are 20 simulated temperature values for 20 plants:

```
X1:
43 48 33 35 36 38 37 47 35 44 31 37 36 44 46 37 36 40 37 46
X2:
45 48 33 38 37 39 43 46 37 49 37 39 41 46 48 42 39 45 39 48
```

A paired test looks at differences in the values for each plant:

```
D:
2  0  0  3  1  1  6 -1  2  5  6  2  5  2  2  5  3  5  2  2
```

[image]

Notice that there is a positive difference $D_I = X_{1i} - X_{2i},$
for $i = 1, 2, \dots, 20,$ for all but one plant. So it is not surprising that a paired test finds
a highly significant difference between the two types of meaurement 
(locations or times) for the plants. Results from R statistical software: P-value almost 0.

```
t.test(X2, X1, pair=T)

        Paired t-test

data:  X2 and X1
t = 5.7558, df = 19, p-value = 1.513e-05
alternative hypothesis: 
   true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 1.686359 3.613641
sample estimates:
mean of the differences 
                   2.65
```

By contrast, if we *incorrectly* run a 2-sample t test on these
data, the information inherent in the pairing is lost, and no
significant difference is found. The P-value is about 9%.

[image]

[As is customary, I have used
a Welch 2-sample t test, which does not require equal population variances, but the pooled 2-sample t test gives nearly the same result for these particular data.]

```
t.test(X2, X1)

    Welch Two Sample t-test

data:  X2 and X1
t = 1.7208, df = 37.79, p-value = 0.09346
alternative hypothesis: 
   true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -0.4680369  5.7680369
sample estimates:
mean of x mean of y 
    41.95     39.30
```

Ordinarily, the two vectors of observations will be positively
correlated for paired data, that is the case here:

```
cor(X1, X2)
[1] 0.9131605
```

Data are positively correlated and on a plot all but one point
lies above the 45-degree line.

[image]

Comment: A brilliant explanation. Thank you very much,